# VB.net Dynamic asp:table created from DataTable duplicating rows - Advice needed

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have an issue with a dynamically created table within my asp form.

To control the page and create the table, the user selects a date range and clicks a Refresh button.

The table creates after being populated in the code behind, but duplicates, 
i.e. 11 rows should populate, but after row 11, rows 12 - 22 are duplicates of 1 - 11.

Interestingly, when clicking a button (created by the code behind, dynamically) the page posts back with the table being as it should rows 1 - 11 and no more. I have replicated the code below in my Page_Load sub.

Please advise, thanks in advance;

```
Protected Sub Refresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    '/*** CREATES CONNECTION STRING AND OPENS CONNECTION TO DB ***\'
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection

    cn.ConnectionString = [String]
    cn.Open()

    '/*** CREATES DateFormat FOR PLACEMENT WITHIN THE SQL ***\'
    Dim dtform As String
    dtform = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

    '/*** DECLARES AND FINDS FROM & TO DATE FOR SQL STATEMENT ***\'
    Dim from As Date
    from = Frmdt.Text

    Dim todat As Date
    todat = Todt.Text

    '/*** EXECUTES SQL & CREATES RECORDSET WITH RecordCount ***\'
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()
    Dim x As Integer

    With rs
        .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        .CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
        .LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic
        .Open("SELECT * FROM DB", cn.ConnectionString)
        x = rs.RecordCount
    End With

    '/*** DECLARES & FILLS DataAdapter, DataSet & DataTable ***\'
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter()

    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, rs, "[Field Headers]")

    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("[Field Headers]")

    '/*** DECLARES ROW COUNTER TO TRACK NUMBER OF ROWS ADDED TO ASP:TABLE ***\'
    Dim rwcntr As Integer

    '/*** DECLARES ROW COUNTER TO EXTRACT DATA FROM DataTable ***\'
    Dim i As Integer

    rwcntr = 1

    '/*** BEGINS LOOP OF DataTable & CREATES ASP:TABLE, ENDING WHEN ROW COUNTER REACHES RecordCount MINUS 1 ***\'
    For i = 0 To x - 1 Step +1

        Dim td As New TableCell()
        Dim td2 As New TableCell()
        Dim td3 As New TableCell()
        Dim td4 As New TableCell()
        Dim td5 As New TableCell()
        Dim td6 As New TableCell()
        Dim td7 As New TableCell()
        Dim td8 As New TableCell()
        Dim td9 As New TableCell()
        Dim td10 As New TableCell()
        Dim td11 As New TableCell()
        Dim td12 As New TableCell()
        Dim td13 As New TableCell()

        Dim tr As New TableRow()

        td.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header1]").ToString()
        td.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td.Font.Size = 8
        td.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td.EnableViewState = True
        td.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td)

        td2.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header2]").ToString()
        td2.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td2.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td2.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td2.Font.Size = 8
        td2.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td2.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td2.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td2.EnableViewState = True
        td2.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td2.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td2)

        td3.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header3]").ToString()
        td3.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td3.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td3.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td3.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td3.Font.Size = 8
        td3.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td3.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td3.EnableViewState = True
        td3.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td3.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td3)

        td4.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header4]").ToString()
        td4.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td4.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td4.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td4.Font.Size = 8
        td4.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td4.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td4.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td4.EnableViewState = True
        td4.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td4.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td4)

        td5.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header5]").ToString()
        td5.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td5.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td5.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td5.Font.Size = 8
        td5.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td5.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td5.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td5.EnableViewState = True
        td5.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td5.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td5)

        td6.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header6]").ToString()
        td6.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td6.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td6.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td6.Font.Size = 8
        td6.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td6.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td6.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td6.EnableViewState = True
        td6.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td6.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td6)

        td7.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header7]").ToString()
        td7.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td7.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td7.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td7.Font.Size = 8
        td7.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td7.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td7.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td7.EnableViewState = True
        td7.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td7.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td7)

        td8.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header8]").ToString()
        td8.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td8.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td8.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td8.Font.Size = 8
        td8.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td8.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td8.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td8.EnableViewState = True
        td8.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td8.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td8)

        td9.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header9]").ToString()
        td9.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td9.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td9.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td9.Font.Size = 8
        td9.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td9.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td9.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td9.Width = 25
        td9.EnableViewState = True
        td9.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td9.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td9)

        'td10.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header10]").ToString()
        'td10.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td10.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td10.ForeColor = Color.Black
        'td10.Font.Size = 8
        td10.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td10.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td10.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td10.EnableViewState = True

        '/*** SHOULD DATA BE AVAILABLE CREATES ASP:BUTTON TO COPY TO CLIPBOARD LATER ***\'
        If Len(dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header10]").ToString()) > 0 Then

            Dim btn As New Button
            td10.Controls.Add(btn)
            btn.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header10]").ToString()
            btn.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            btn.Font.Size = 8
            td10.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
            td10.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
            btn.EnableViewState = True
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf OnDbleClick

        End If
        tr.Controls.Add(td10)

        td11.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header11]").ToString()
        td11.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td11.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td11.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td11.Font.Size = 8
        td11.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td11.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td11.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td11.EnableViewState = True
        td11.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td11.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td11)

        td12.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header12]").ToString()
        td12.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td12.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td12.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td12.Font.Size = 8
        td12.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td12.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td12.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td12.EnableViewState = True
        td12.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td12.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td12)

        td13.Text = dt.Rows(i)("[Field Header13]").ToString()
        td13.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        td13.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc")
        td13.ForeColor = Color.Black
        td13.Font.Size = 8
        td13.BorderStyle = WebControls.BorderStyle.Inset
        td13.BorderColor = Color.Black
        td13.BorderWidth = 1.5
        td13.EnableViewState = True
        td13.HorizontalAlign = WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        td13.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle
        tr.Controls.Add(td13)


        '/*** ADDS ROW ONCE CELLS ARE COMPLETE ***\'
        itemstable.Controls.AddAt(rwcntr, tr)
        rwcntr = rwcntr + 1

    Next

end sub
```

Comment: Have run your query in your management studio?

Comment: Hi, yes apologies. I have run the SQL in Oracle Developer with no issues. I've even stepped through the VB code and it only loops 11 times as it should.

Comment: have you tried to output data to debug window when you run it to verify that it is only going 11 times and it is never called again for some reason.

Comment: Hi. The issue seemed to be, because the query was repeated in the Page_load postback code. It would duplicate the rows on initial query, then when posting back again the duplicate rows would vanish. Still haven't found a work around/correct code. Any advice?